# Transfer data from one computer to another while script is running

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, server, client

I've been researching how to do this, but I haven't found a good answer for my problem.
I have a script running on my server and it constantly output messages on the console.
I want to send these messages to another computer. Both are in the same network.
I'm not sure how to make this work Async.
I need the script to keep running, and when a output is sent to the console, I want it to be displayed on the other computer.
I've been looking into sockets, pipe, etc, but I'm fairly new to this.
Can you guys recommend a library or way that I could make this work?
Thank you.

Comment: first: other computer will need some script to receive data from server. it may run as normal socket in server mode, or HTTP server which get requests from other program. Or you may use other programs to deliver message - you may run MQTT server and your server may send message to this MQTT and other computer (or many computers) may periodically check if there is new message and get it and display.

Answer (score 2):

This type of functionality is typically better handled at OS level than from inside your script. You don't say much about your environment in your post, so I will answer assuming you are working in a UNIX-like environment.

If this is a one-off task, a (very) easy way to do that is with `hose` / `faucet` (parts of the `netpipes` utilities, most probably packaged for your OS distribution).

Just redirect your console output to the hose utility :

```
hose remote_hostname port --out yourscript
```

On the remote machine :

```
faucet port --in cat
```

`nc` ("the TCP/IP swiss knife") might also serve your interests.

If you have to consolidate this into a more flexible and permanent solution, then writing to `syslog` from your (python ?) script is easy (have a look at module `syslog`). The OS configuration will allow you to send `syslog` entries to whatever place fits you (local console, write to a file, send to a remote syslog daemon, ...).